# SMS to verify phone number on android application

Tags: android

How to send a phone number verification code like whatsapp in an app android studio 2.3.2

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the third party API to do so, check the below link 
http://www.androidhive.info/2015/08/android-adding-sms-verification-like-whatsapp-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

you can use below step :

1. Adding require permissions in the Manifest
2. Create a BroadcastReceiver class
3. Adding permission for receiving SMS
4. Adding permission in mainfest for detection OTP(Verify ) code